# How to use implement AES_DECRYPT() of MySQL by Python

Tags: python, mysql, security, aes

I am trying to write a python code which has same functionarities of `AES_ENCRYPT` and `AES_DECRYPT` of MySQL.
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/ja/encryption-functions.html

I want to encrypt and decrypt data between MySQL and Python.

For example, I want to decrypt data by python, which is encrypted by `AES_ENCRYPT` of MySQL.

And I want to decrypt data by `AES_DECRYPT` of MySQL, which is encrypted by Python vice versa.

I found a example of `AES_ENCRYPT` in Python.
https://www.maykinmedia.nl/blog/2012/nov/15/mysql-aes_encrypt-python/

Does anyone know how to implement the decryption part?

Comment: I'm not really sure what exactly you are after. The language of the question suggests that you want to use aes_encrypt() / aes_decrypt() functions provided by MySQL in python. In this case you just pass the parameters to the MySQL query and MySQL takes care of the encryption / decryption. But the linked example mimicks the said aes_encrypt() function within python, which has nothing to do with MySQL. So, which approach do you actually need?

Comment: You may [edit] your question to provide more details about your requirement.

Comment: I edited my question.

Comment: Is there any reason for complicating your life? Stick to one or the other approach. Btw, the parameters used for encrypting the data should be used for decrypting as well. AES is a symmetric key encryption.

Comment: I have a sql file of MySQL, and it has some encrypted data. I want to read it by Python without MySQL. Yes. I know AES needs a key and I know the key used in MySQL.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I did it finally.

```
def mysql_aes_decrypt(val, key):

    def mysql_aes_key(key):
        final_key = bytearray(16)
        for i, c in enumerate(key):
            final_key[i % 16] ^= ord(key[i])
        return bytes(final_key)

    k = mysql_aes_key(key)

    cipher = AES.new(k, AES.MODE_ECB)

    return cipher.decrypt(val).decode()
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for this code. I see one issue in the code when I use it. `UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xf3 in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)`. This error stems from the last line: `return cipher.decrypt(val).decode()`. If I just keep it as `cipher.decrypt(val)`, there is no error, but the characters are not readable.

Comment: @Raghuram yup, that's because you haven't decoded it, the issue is with your value, read the link in the question first