# How to decrypt one column of a SELECT * statement in Python?

Tags: python, mysql, encryption

I have a `SELECT` statement in MySQL that fetches all the rows that matches a criteria as follows:

```
SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE sl_no=number;
```

and the table structure is as follows:

```
--------------------------
sl_no|val_1|val_2|val_3
---------------------------
1|a|b|c
2|d|e|f
3|g|h|i
----------------------------
```

One of the columns, `val_1` is encrypted. I need to decrypt this column when the `SELECT` query above is executed. I know how to do it in MySQL as below:

```
SET @key_str = key;
SET block_encryption_mode=aes-256-ecb;
SELECT AES_DECRYPT(FROM_BASE64(val_1), @key_str) FROM table WHERE sl_no=number;
```

I want to replicate the same process in Python using MySQLdb. My attempts:

1. I first tried the answer mentioned in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51134744/how-to-use-implement-aes-decrypt-of-mysql-by-python) question, which did not work
2. I then tried to run the commands shown above in Python itself the following way

```
database = MySQLdb.connect(host=host_name,user=databaseUsername,passwd=databasePassword,db=databaseName,cursorclass=MySQLdb.cursors.DictCursor)
set_query="SET @key_str=(%s)%config['key_str']"
set_block="SET block_encryption_mode=(%s)config['aes_mode']"
database.query(set_query)
database.query(set_block)
```

However, I keep getting the following error: `_mysql_exceptions.ProgrammingError: (1064, "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near` key_string `at line 1")`. for this line: `set_query="SET @key_str=(%s)%config['key_str']`

Comment: 1. There are several missing double quotes in your code, so it can't possibly run. 2. Don't you need to quote the string in @key_string='string'? Doing this using Python's % operator is probably a bad idea. I'm not familiar with MySQL, but the Python library you are using almost certainly has a way of passing parameters to queries that takes care of quoting automagically.

Comment: Val_1 is saved as encrypted format in database or is it in simple format?

Comment: @KetanVekariya val_1 is encrypted in the database.

Comment: @TurePålsson The missing double quotes are formatting issues here. I will fix them. However, in my script, they are correctly written.

Comment: @Raghuram please provide insert sql query so that we can perform test and help you for the same

Comment: @KetanVekariya Sorry, I did not understand your question fully. Do you mean the process by which the column `val_1` is inserted into the DB and encrypted?

Comment: Shouldn't the ` % config['key_str']` bit be outside the double quotes? Which brings us back to point 2 of my previous comment.